# Need a formula that generates a new time that is a random interval from the last time but between 25 and 30 mins

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I am using Excel to try to come up with a schedule for when I will be doing my rounds. I have to do them wwithin thirty (30) minutes from the last time and I don't want to go less than 25 minutes apart. I also don't care if some are 30 mins.

Therefore how do I come up with a formula where I add a random time interval between 25 and 30 minutes to the previous row's time value?

Comment: If *rand()* returns a pseudo-random number between 0 and 1.0 inclusive, then the the next interval is `5*rand() + 25`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say in A1 you enter the time of the first round:

```
08:00
```

Then you can create the following formula in A2:

```
=A1+time(0;randbetween(25;30);0)
```

(Replace semicolons with commas if that's what your regional settings dictate.)
And copy/paste that cell downwards for as many rounds you need to run.